# How to send email if date in mysql is today

Tags: php, mysql, email, cron, jobs

What I really need is to create function in php to send email when field_number 7 date is today.
And I need send data for only for example lead_id 1 if lead_id 1 field_number 7 data is today.
When script will be created I want to add cron job to this file, so that it each day would check current day.
My mysql data looks like below:

[image: Mysql data]

I am not programmer, but as far as I know code must look something like this:

```
//authentication for database
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "admin";
$password = "xxxxxx";

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

//select a database to work with
$selected = mysql_select_db("notification",$dbhandle) 
or die("Could not select examples");

//execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_lead WHERE pass_expiry >= DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY");

//variable for email message
$emailBody = "";
$headers = 'From: Pass Validity Reminder' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: myemail@email.com' . "\r\n" .
'Cc: ccemail@Wemail. com' . "\r\n".
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$to = "myemail@email.com";

//fetch tha data from the database 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
```

Comment: Use mysqli functions instead of mysql functions. The later are depreciated and using the former with prepared statements will help prevent SQL Injection.

Comment: You will also need a way to marks as sent so that if the cron job runs again on the same date, it won't send the email again.

Comment: You definitely don't need to be using PHP's ancient, insecure, and deprecated mysql_ API.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code writing service, it helps programmers with coding problems. Just copying the first code you find on a similar question without changing anything except, incorrectly, the interval, does not qualify as trying it on your own. You will get pointed out problems or get tips, but noone will do the complete job for you (unless he is bored). To find stackoverflow helpful, you would need to learn at least a basic understanding of programming (which you can do with help from stackoverflow, but if you want others to just do the coding for you, you may want to hire a student).

Answer (score 0):

Considering the table structure in the image use below SQL statement to get all matching records

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM YOURTABLENAME WHERE lead_id='1' and field_number='7' and value=CURRENT_DATE();
```

**Updated:**

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT lead_id, form_id, field_number, value FROM YOURTABLENAME WHERE field_number='7' and value=CURRENT_DATE();
```

Above query will provide all records with `field_number` 7 and `value` is today date

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    if($row['lead_id']==1){
        //send email to all lead_id 1
    }

    if($row['lead_id']==2){
        //send email to all lead_id 1
    }

    .... Add leads to whom you have to send email
}
```

Comment: Thank you that is good. Can you please tell how I can in email body values for current lead_id? For example if current date is for lead_id 2 how to send all lead_id 2 values?

Comment: Check **updated** note on how to send email based on `lead_id`

Answer (score -1):

If you want to retrieve data based on current date then you can use this sql query

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_lead WHERE pass_expiry=CURRENT_DATE()");
```

This query will select all the today's date data